# "EstablishContextException" error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscard

I've downloaded *Python-2.7* and *pyscard-1.7.0.win32-py2.7* and installed them on my computer to use my ACR122U smart card reader in my Windows-7.

After that I wrote the below program :

```
import sys
import time
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages")

from smartcard.scard import *
import smartcard.util
from smartcard.System import readers

class Metro:

    isConnected = False
    isLoaded = False
    isAuthenticated = False
 .
 . # Methods censored.
 .
```

When I want to run the program, I receive these errors:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> Connecting to the reader: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AmirEbrahim\Desktop\metro.py", line 195, in <module>
    m.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AmirEbrahim\Desktop\metro.py", line 63, in connect
    r = readers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\System.py", line 41, in readers
    return smartcard.reader.ReaderFactory.ReaderFactory.readers(groups)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\reader\ReaderFactory.py", line 58, in readers
    zreaders += fm(groups)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCReader.py", line 107, in readers
    hcontext = PCSCContext().getContext()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCContext.py", line 53, in __init__
    PCSCContext.instance = PCSCContext.__PCSCContextSingleton()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCContext.py", line 40, in __init__
    raise EstablishContextException(hresult)
EstablishContextException: <unprintable EstablishContextException object>
>>>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Permission issues maybe? Did you try to run as admin?

Comment: @Bernhard, Yes I tried that already, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and  installed an older version of PyScard from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscard/files/pyscard/) and now it works fine.
[image]